# WPF TextBox Text Coercion

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, trim

I have to implement WPF TextBox that will provide trimmed Text via binding.
At first glance this task looked fairly straightforward to me. I decided to use dependency property value coercion. Below I wrote my code, but this seems not to work. I get not trimmed strings in my bound properties. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should take another approach?

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    static MyTextBox()
    {
        TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, null, new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceText)));
    }

    private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        string s = basevalue as string;
        if(s != null)
        {
            return s.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

I added simple window to my app for testing. 
Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:TextBoxDemo="clr-namespace:TextBoxDemo"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Grid>
    <TextBoxDemo:MyTextBox x:Name="textBox1"
                           Width="120"
                           Height="23"
                           Margin="55,73,0,0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Text="{Binding Text}" />
    <TextBoxDemo:MyTextBox x:Name="textBox2"
                           Width="120"
                           Height="23"
                           Margin="286,184,0,0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Text="{Binding Text}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _text;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("|{0}|", _text));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. MyTextBox's Text property value will never contain a space at the beginning or at the end. What exactly do you try to accomplish ?

Comment: I added code of my testing app. The MessageBox shows not trimmed text.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, value coercion doesn't work well with binding.

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c404360c-8e31-4a85-9762-0324ed8812ef/) talks about the same issue and proposes one or two workarounds.
One of them is to call `UpdateTarget()` on the TextBox's binding expression explicitly:

```
textBox1.GetBindingExpression(MyTextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a solution but when to call UpdateTarget? My TextBox should not require any other actions from programmer than declaring binding in XAML.

Comment: .. inside your CoerceText() function > right after you done setting up the edited value , call UpdateTarget()